# How to reverse string by dashed in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, reverse

I getting position result like:

```
10-12-1
```

and want to result like:

```
1-12-10
```

I'm applying string function `REVERSE()` than result come like

```
query  :  select REVERSE("10-12-1")
result : 1-21-01
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Will the result always be in the format `XX-XX-XX`?

Comment: yes, but parent position have only one position than not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
select concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX('10-12-1', '-', -1) , '-' 
     , substr('10-12-1',instr('10-12-1',"-") + 1, instr('10-12-1',"-")) 
     , LEFT('10-12-1',LOCATE('-','10-12-1') - 1));
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/36817)**

Answer (score 6):

You can use simple trick to parse it with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and `GROUP_CONCAT` back to one string:

```
SELECT id, col, GROUP_CONCAT(val ORDER BY n DESC SEPARATOR '-') AS reversed
FROM
(
SELECT id, col,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.col, '-', n.n), '-', -1) AS val, n
FROM tab t 
CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.col, '-', '')))
) sub
GROUP BY id
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0662/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ id  ║      col        ║    reversed    ║
╠═════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╣
║  1  ║ 1-12-10         ║ 10-12-1        ║
║  2  ║ 111-12-10       ║ 10-12-111      ║
║  3  ║ 11123-2-103223  ║ 103223-2-11123 ║
╚═════╩═════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Keep in mind that this solution will work for more than 3 parts with variable length (`1-20-300-4000-500000-600000-7`).